# Go: cannot run non main package?

Tags: go

I always get error

> cannot run non-main package

Its just a code from [github](https://github.com/NebulousLabs/fastrand).

Answer (score 5):

the program that you link to doesn't contain a main function (or more properly in GO terms, a package named main, that itself contains a function called main which is the entry point of the program (well before main there can also be a function called init that is used to initialize data. take a look at the [flag package](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) ))

The fastrand repository that you linked to is supposed to be run as a library from other go programs that are going to use the functions it exposes. For example to get an integer from 0 to n [0, n) using this library you can use this toy program.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/NebulousLabs/fastrand"
)

func main() {
        //prints a random int [0,10) using fastrand
        fmt.Printf("random int:%d\n", fastrand.Intn(10))
}
```

put that in a directory under your GOPATH, (let's say you name it foo.go) run

```
go get github.com/NebulousLabs/fastrand; 
go build foo.go; 
./foo;
```